# Python - read from a file

Tags: file, input

I want to read from a file that looks like the below, and put in a list that looks like [[Sten Saker][20.0] [1.0]], I don't know how to do it.

```
Sten S ̈aker 20.0 1.0
Olle Ojamn 19.0 2.0 
Charlie Chans 18.0 3.0
```

Comment: do you mean looks like below?

Comment: You should create a CSV file, read from that file, split on new lines, split on commas.